# Ubuntu 14.04 LibreOffice NOT opening

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

When I try to open LibreOffice it does not open. I have tried to research this and have not found an answer. I tried opening it from terminal and here is the error that I received:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program$ libreoffice 
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: relocation error:
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/../ure-link/lib/libuno_sal.so.3: 
symbol pthread_mutexattr_in��   ���{���h�utexattr_setkind_np, version
GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time
reference
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the ppa for the latest libreoffice:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Try doing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice
```

If that doesn't work, then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

This should work unless you have completely messed libreoffice up.

Comment: I ended up fixing this. Just got the time to update this. I did the last thing you posted, and then went in and manually any trace of libreoffice that I could find. After that, I reinstalled via the Software Manager.  It seems to be doing okay now!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Ubuntu 18.04 and was only able to resolve it by doing

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice
```

and then visiting https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/ to get the newest Deb files from there. 
I then proceeded to unzip the contents, navigated to the folder and installed using

```
sudo dpkg -i some_file
```

until I had resolved all the dependencies and I could do `sudo dpkg -i *` without dependency errors being reported.

I am sure there was a better way to install the files, but it is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get install openoffice

Everything works now.

Enyoy the life.